# find and replace arry in plist

Tags: shell, osx-yosemite

I'll try to find and replace an array in a plist. I can write with defaults write an array without an problem, but I can not delete an array.

The plist is: `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plisty`

I would like to delete:

<dict>
 <key>LSHandlerPreferredVersions</key>
 <dict>
 <key>LSHandlerRoleAll</key>
  <string>-</string>
 </dict>
 <key>LSHandlerRoleAll</key>
 <string>com.apple.mail</string>
 <key>LSHandlerURLScheme</key>
 <string>mailto</string>
</dict>

and replace it with:

<dict>
 <key>LSHandlerPreferredVersions</key>
 <dict>
 <key>LSHandlerRoleAll</key>
  <string>-</string>
 </dict>
 <key>LSHandlerRoleAll</key>
 <string>com.microsoft.outlook</string>
 <key>LSHandlerURLScheme</key>
 <string>mailto</string>
</dict>

I've searched the internet but I do not found the solution ;-) Can somebody help me? I thank you in advance for your help, Netzmeister

Comment: @duDE Are you sure that your edit here is correct?

Comment: @duDE: No, it is not the same. The first ist for Apple Mail <string>com.apple.mail</string> and the second for Microsoft Outlook <string>com.microsoft.outlook</string>

Comment: So the problem is: how to replace <string>com.apple.mail</string> with <string>com.microsoft.outlook</string> ? This can easily be done with Notepad++ ...

Comment: @duDE: ;-) yes, I know. But I want it to to with a shell-script.

Comment: @all: I did it with the following shell-script:
#!/bin/bash
PLISTPATH="Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices"
PLISTFILE="com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist"

plutil -convert xml1 ${PLISTPATH}/${PLISTFILE}

SEARCH="com.apple.mail"
REPLACE="com.microsoft.outlook"

perl -p -i -e 's/'${SEARCH}'/'${REPLACE}'/g' ${PLISTPATH}/${PLISTFILE}
plutil -convert binary1 ${PLISTPATH}/${PLISTFILE}

/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user

Comment: I'm not sure about your needs, but since the [plist](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/plist.5.html) seems to be a normal text file, under Linux is enough to write (it is a single line) `sed 's/<string>com.apple.mail<\/string>/<string>com.microsoft.outlook<\/string>/g' AAA.txt` where instead of `AAA.txt` you should  write your _filename_.  Check and if it works fine write the same line adding `-i` to modify the file inside (`sed -i ...`). You may need to add `sudo` for _root privilege_. Check it.if it works I'll write a more extended answer.

Comment: @Hastur: Thanks for your reply. Nothing happens. I see only the result on the screen, but the file AAA.txt is untouched. If I add -i the error message is: sed: 1: "AAA.txt": invalid command code A.
I did it with perl and this workaround is good for me.

Comment: When I tried it worked. I can only imagine that you added the `-i` to the end of the line and not in the beginning, and that _BSD_ `sed` didn't like it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the [plist](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/plist.5.html) seems to be a normal text file, under Linux is enough to write (it is a single line)

> `sed 's/<string>com.apple.mail<\/string>/<string>com.microsoft.outlook<\/string>/g' AAA.txt`

where instead of `AAA.txt` you should write your `filename`.
It will show the result on the standard output (the `tty` in which you are working).

After that you checked if it worked fine you can write the same line adding the parameter `-i` to modify the file inside

> **`sed -i 's/<string>com.apple.mail<\/string>/<string>com.microsoft.outlook<\/string>/g' AAA.txt`**

---

**Some explanation more**:

```
 sed -i 's/OLD/NEW/g' NameOfYourFile
```

- The command above will search inside the file `NameOfYourFile` all the occurrences of the string `OLD` and will substitute it with the string `NEW`.
- You should identify properly the **keyword** that you want substitute, in this case with the tags included: `<string>com.apple.mail</string>`.
  Since there is a `/` you have to  protect it with a `\` before and keyword becomes  `<string>com.apple.mail<\/string>`. (You have to apply the same logic to the second string).
- The parameter `-i` will substitute the string in the file without display the result on the screen. For this can be better to try it before without.
- Under `BSD` it can be important the [order of parameters](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37523/order-of-parameters-for-command-line-tools), so `sed ... -i` could be not the same of `sed -i ...` and give you the error you find.
- You may need to add `sudo` in the beginning to obtain the *root privilege*, or to run that command from a *root shell*, if you are not allowed as normal user to modify that file. (You can check it with `ls -l NameOfYourFile`).

**Notes**

from `man sed`

> **-i**[SUFFIX], **--in-place**[=SUFFIX]

```
          edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Realy. But it does not work with Yosemite 10.10.5. No problem at all. I did it with perl and this is working perfect.

Comment: You're welcome. This is a so basic and old command that I didn't promptly realise that we were using different versions of `sed`. To make it works as it is under BSD you should use [GNU sed](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/195595) `gsed` instead of `sed`.  Or you should use with `sed -i.bak -E ... `  or with `sed -i'' -E` ... (if you have time check if it works on your system).

Comment: Dear Hastur. I think I leave it. I have no nerves left >;-) 

The manpage on yosemite tells me: "The -E, -a and -i options are non-standard FreeBSD extensions and may not be available on other operating systems."


By the way. How can I close my question? I've solved my problem with perl.

I very thank you and kind regards, Netzmeister